# Search Jaeger tags in different spans

Tags: jaeger

I have tags in different spans in Jaeger. Specific one tag 'error' is in server span and second 'account' is in internal span. How can I search for both tags in Jaeger UI?

I want to have something like:
`error=true account=xxx`. But while I'm trying this - I get nothing. while I'm searching each tag separately - all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported in Jaeger. All search conditions are applied to the same span (via implicit AND).